# How to initialise Firebase App Check in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-app-check

I was wondering how can i initialise firebase app check using angular.

I am using angular fire but I am not sure how to initalise firebase app check before using any of the services

the docs have this

> Add the following initialization code to your application, before you access any Firebase services.
>
> ```
> firebase.initializeApp({
>   // Your firebase configuration object
> });
>
> const appCheck = firebase.appCheck();
> // Pass your reCAPTCHA v3 site key (public key) to activate(). Make sure this
> // key is the counterpart to the secret key you set in the Firebase console.
> appCheck.activate('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy-1234567890abcd');
> ```

But how can this be done in app module. Currently i import angular fire like so

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ...
  ],
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
  ],
]
```

Update:

I know this is probably not yet part of the angular fire library due to how new firebase app-check is but I have noticed there is a native firebase library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/app-check

I am happy for this to be used (e.g. somehow overriding the native firebase js object) as long as the code is able to apply it in the correct location before any services are called and that it gives no compilation errors in typescript

For reference my versions are as follows:

Angular:
10.2.5

Firebase:
8.6.0

AngularFire:
6.1.5

The debug localhost version must also work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this:

```
// firebase-initialization.ts
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/app-check';

// Environment Config
import { environment } from './path/to/environments';

const app = firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
const appCheck = app.appCheck()
appCheck.activate('');
```

Then import the file in the app module as:

```
import "firebase-initialization"
```

Comment: I have tried this solution, but after I did I get: @firebase/app-check: FirebaseError: AppCheck: Fetch server returned an HTTP error status. HTTP status: 403. (appCheck/fetch-status-error). Also when calling cloud functions I get: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unauthenticated although I havn’t added any code to enforce it in my cloud functions. My web app used to work without errors. I have enabled App Check in the firebase console. Do the import: AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase) still need to be in app module?

Comment: Yep, it should be still in the app module as it will configure other stuff.

Comment: I tried this but I am getting an error right off the bat: 
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'firebase-initialization' in 'my-angular-project-path\src\app'
Not sure what's going on but I've named it firebase-initialization.ts and it's in the src/app folder, same as my app.module.ts file.

Answer (score 3):

You could also achieve this with a service and interceptor (code below). The service should probably add some kind of caching of tokens (shorter TTLs for more security, longer TTLs for lower costs).  See [Enable App Check with reCAPTCHA Enterprise in web apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/recaptcha-enterprise-provider) for more detail.

To keep the service implementation simple, the token caching code is not included.

The service holds the logic to get a token using App Check.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseApp, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { AppCheck, AppCheckTokenResult, getToken, initializeAppCheck, ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider } from 'firebase/app-check';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppCheckService {

  app: FirebaseApp;
  appCheck: AppCheck;

  constructor() {
    this.app = initializeApp(environment.firebase);

    // Create a ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider instance using reCAPTCHA Enterprise.
    this.appCheck = initializeAppCheck(this.app, {
      provider: new ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider(environment.recaptchaEnterpriseKey),
      isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true // Set to true to allow auto-refresh.
    });
  }


  async getToken(): Promise<AppCheckTokenResult | undefined> {
    let appCheckTokenResponse;
    try {
      appCheckTokenResponse = await getToken(this.appCheck);
    } catch (err) {
      // TODO: Handle any errors if the token was not retrieved.
      return;
    }
    return appCheckTokenResponse;
  }
}
```

This service can then be used by an interceptor which is responsible for adding a `X-Firebase-AppCheck` HTTP header with the token.

```js
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppCheckTokenResult } from '@firebase/app-check';
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { AppCheckService } from '../services/app-check.service';

@Injectable()
export class AppCheckInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private readonly appCheckService: AppCheckService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return from(this.appCheckService.getToken()).pipe(
            take(1), // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60196923/828547.
            switchMap((token: AppCheckTokenResult | undefined) => {
                if (token) {
                    request = request.clone({
                        setHeaders: { "X-Firebase-AppCheck": token?.token },
                    });
                }
                return next.handle(request);
            }),
        );
    }
}
```

You will need to add `recaptchaEnterpriseKey` to your Angular environment files

```js
export const environment = {
  recaptchaEnterpriseKey: '6LfGni324khkjh324hkDSFsdfSfsdm',
};
```

And finally add the interceptor to your `app.module.ts` file

```js
providers: [
 {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AppCheckInterceptor,
      multi: true,
 },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the event DOMContentLoaded to make app check work with my angularJS app, maybe you can try it:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var appCheck = firebase.appCheck()
  appCheck.activate('captchatokenid')
})
```