# How do I implement firebase app-check in my Angular 12 application

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire, angular-universal

I've tried the solutions provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67908846/how-to-initialise-firebase-app-check-in-angular.)

Here's my code

```
// firebase-init.ts
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

import 'firebase/app-check';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

const app = firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
const appCheck = app.appCheck();

appCheck.activate('KEY_HERE');
```

And here's my import to `app.module.ts`

```
// app.module.ts
import './firebase-init'
```

[image: I get this error after running the code]

I'm using `Angular Universal` for Server Side Rendering.
Please help. What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

By the look of it it seems you are using the DEBUG TOKEN VALUE (generated in the console).
Try using reCaptcha key and see if that resolves the issue.

Replace this:
`appCheck.activate('6LeatjUbAAAAAGn_iRsWgEFyf-lubXOUkaqyEJLJ');`

With this:
`appCheck.activate('reCAPTCHA secret key');`

Hint: click on the app row instead of context menu icon (three dots).
It will slide down another row where you can see the reCaptcha button.