# Using Firebase App Check Debug Provider with Angular

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-app-check

This is not a duplicate of [How to initialise Firebase App Check in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67908846/how-to-initialise-firebase-app-check-in-angular) because I can successfully initialise an app using reCAPTCHA Enterprise. This question is about initialising an app using the Debug Provider.

The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/debug-provider#web-version-8_1) recommends using the Debug Provider when testing from localhost. Specifically

> In your debug build, enable debug mode by setting
> `self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN` to true before you initialize App
> Check. For example:

```js
self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;
initializeAppCheck(app, { /* App Check options */ });
```

How can this be achieved in an Angular application? It's not clear what `self` is referencing or where this code snippet should be placed.

Answer (score 7):

After a few experiments and guesses, setting `FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN` on the *window* object worked. I did this by adding the following to my `app.component.ts` constructor

```js
(<any>window).FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;
```

The precise code to extend the `window` object may change over time, but I took this syntax from [How do you explicitly set a new property on `window` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript).

Comment: this is just weird, I can't find any info in the angularfire library on the FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a new global variable like the follow:

```js
declare global {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-var
  var FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN: boolean | string | undefined;
}

self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = environment.appCheckDebug;
```

Answer (score 0):

I based on the app check docs changed that property of "self" by this way:

```
    (self as any).FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;
```

And I wrote it in the service where I call the API protected by app check

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully initialize my app check with debug token in Angular with @angular/fire with

```
import { ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider, initializeAppCheck, provideAppCheck } from '@angular/fire/app-check';

provideAppCheck(() => {
       const appCheckConfig = {
          provider: new 
    ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider(environment.recaptchaEnterpriseSiteKey),
          isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true,
        };
        appCheckConfig['token'] = `my-debug-token`; 
        return initializeAppCheck(getApp(), appCheckConfig);
    }),
```

in my app.module.ts.
And of course need to add your debug token to the console.firebase.google.com -> App Check -> Apps -> Your app -> Manage debug tokens.

And need to avoid deploying this.